# words in the list in Python

Tags: python, list

How can I get a one word school from the list ['s', 'c', 'h', 'o', 'o', 'l']?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [`str.join(iterable)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable iterable. A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string values in seq, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

I.e. `''.join(parts)`

As indicated in the description, this works for all iterables of strings, not just for lists of characters (single-letter strings).

Answer (score 2):

must have been asked/answered a million times, but here it is:

```
''.join(['s', 'c', 'h', 'o', 'o', 'l'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
your_list = ['s', 'c', 'h', 'o', 'o', 'l']
new_string = "".join(your_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l=['s', 'c', 'h', 'o', 'o', 'l']
>>> print ''.join(l)
school
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you . Even though ''.join(['s', 'c', 'h', 'o', 'o', 'l']) works I personally love using the method shown below ..
Anyway its ur call :)

```
>>> word
['s', 'c', 'h', 'o', 'o', 'l']
>>> reduce(lambda a,x:a+x,word)
'school'
>>>
```